# How Can I create a model of a temporary table in laravel 8?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a problem with temporary table, i don't know if can create model in Laravel 8 of Temporary Tables.

`DB::insert( DB::raw( "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempproducts") );`

I think what i can create model before i create temporary table, but i don't know if work.

Comment: DDL operation is not INSERT.

Comment: You can use DB::unprepared for execution an arbitrary SQL.